# Llamada GET desde app

Tags: c#, vb.net, api

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de escritorio que se conecta a la API a través de "HttpClient" la autenticación de la API es mediante "token", por lo que hago login a través de mi app con POST que envío en formato jSon. Sin embargo, lo que yo necesito ahora es un archivo jSon que se obtiene en el browser con otra URL que no es de la API (supongo porque es otra URL), aquí la autenticación se hace con un formulario en pantalla con los mismos datos user y password. Si yo llevo esa URL a Postman sólo funciona si le entrego en el header un "sessionid".

Cómo puedo conectarme a esa URL desde mi app? debo usar una cookie? debo conseguir ese jSon con otro tipo de autenticación?

Esta es la llamada que hago en el browser para obtener el jSon:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la llamada por Postman para obtener el token de login:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo supones bien, lo que tienes es la url a un sitio web comun, el cual usa autenticacion por cookies

Para obtener la informacion podrias navegarlo usando el control `WebBrowser`

[WebBrowser Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser?view=netframework-4.8)

Entonces podras interacturar con el html de la pagina, ingresar las credenciales y realizar la accion click del boton que autentica y redirecciona a la pagina con los datos

Si bien es un control no necesitas de un winform, puedes instanciar la clase para usarlo desde codigo

[WebBrowser Element Events and Values](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/547451/WebBrowser-Element-Events-and-Values)

analiza como en el evento `DocumentCompleted` puede acceder al `html` de la pagina que navega accediando a controles usando

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("input id")
```

lo mismo con las acciones de los botones usando

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("button id").InvokeMember("Click");
```

asi interactuas con la pagina usando codigo

---

Si usar este componente no te convence, se podria evaluar otro como ser `Selenium`, si bien es una libreria que se utiliza para crear test que pruebas sitios web, se podrian usar en tu codigo para interactuar y navegar el sitio obteniendo los datos del html

[Getting Started with WebDriver C# in 10 Minutes](https://www.automatetheplanet.com/getting-started-webdriver/)

[Selenium CSharp](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-c-sharp/)

Comment: Gracias, me imagino que podré unir un mismo login para esto y para API, quiero decir que el usuario podrá ingresar "solo" una vez sus credenciales y yo poder hacer esas 2 peticiones. Igualmente necesito el token para las llamdas a la api.

Comment: Por qué me descarga el archivo de inmediato y no me pide login?. Tiene que ver con las cookies almacenadas en mi equipo? Y qué pasaría si el usuario nunca usó el browser?

Comment: no te pide el login donde ? cuando lo accedes desde el browser, postman, httpclient. Las cookies se persisten si asi lo indicas en el login con lo cual podria autenticar directamente, para probarlo realiza un borrado de las cookies del browser para validarlo

Comment: Entiendo, tienes razón ya he borrado historial. Una última cosa: la primera pantalla de inicio será este webbrowser ya que sólo muestra solamente un form de login (2 textbox + 1 botón), entonces quiero capturar el evento cuando el usuario haga login efectivo, es decir, que al hacer click te logre direccionar pero no mostrar esa pantalla al usuario sino redireccionar a mi formulario principal de la app.? cómo lo harías? he probado con capturar el evento del botón pero no me sirve cuando las credenciales son false.

Comment: si las credenciales son falsas entiendo el html deberia reflejar esta situacion, por lo que deberias acceder al dom del html y parsear en la busqueda del mensaje o indicador que refleje el ingreso incorrecto, si esto pasa no muestras la pantalla principal. Recuerda que esto lo harias en un form que abres desde el Main() que esta en Program.cs si pasa la validacion entonces recien asignas el Application.Run(), sino pasa lo informas y dejas pasar no ejecutandose la aplicacion

Comment: Cuando quiero descargar el archivo por código me pide siempre en el header la cookie "sessionid". Si hago un container del request no me trae esa cookie. De dónde la puedo extraer o crear? La otra alternativa que tengo es usar el mismo webbroser pero no sé cómo manejar el cuadro de dialogo que muestra y que necesito evitar que aparezca.

Comment: Es que la cookies de session no puedes controlarlo, se supone que al autenticarte se asigna a la instancia del browser, pero tienes que pasar por el proceso de autenticacion si es que hay un form para esta accion. Si usas el webbrowser podras interactuar con la pagina, pero para eso necesitas aprender a usar el document que se crea para acceder al html en el evento complete

Comment: Entiendo el dom del html, pero en todos los eventos del webbrowser me aparece el cuadro de diálogo para guardar el jSon, lo que yo quiero es evitar ese mensaje y guardar ese jSon en una variable. Mi aplicación se logea en una determinada url pero a la vez necesito guardar el Json que está en otra url diferente al del login. No entiendo como evitar ese cuadro de diálogo, cuando entro a la url en el Chrome me muestra el Json en el <body> y no un mensaje para descargarlo.

Comment: si navegas la url en el IE se genera ese mismo efecto con el cuadro de dialogo para guardar el json ? Si navegas una url y te autenticas no entiendo que tiene que ver esa otra url diferentes, salvo que este en el mismo sitio, pero no te explican bien. se que el control webBrowser tienee eventos para detectar los mensajes y podes suprimirlos, seria cuestion de estudiar un poco el control

Comment: Si entro en IE el json me lo muestra en el body, o sea por pantalla. Si llamo a esa misma url en mi weBrowser me muestra un showdialog para abrirlo/guardarlo: es ésto lo que quiero suprimir. Por lo que leo en foros, es imposible suprimirlo.